# How to Running celeryd as a daemon in ubuntu?

Tags: python, django, initialization, celery, django-celery

i am trying to install an init.d script, to run celery for scheduling tasks. when i tried to start it by `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start`, it throws error `"User does not exist: 'celery'"`

my celery configuration file (`/etc/default/celeryd`) contains these:

```
# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

i know that these are wrong that is why it throws error.

The [documentation](http://ask.github.io/celery/cookbook/daemonizing.html) just says this:

```
CELERYD_USER
User to run celeryd as. Default is current user.
```

nothing more about it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a celery user and group to your Ubuntu ? Or just comment out the CELERYD_USER and CELERYD_GROUP options to run it as the current user...

Comment: @Serafeim thanks. i comment out the `CELERYD_USER` and `CELERYD_GROUP` now it works. anyway do you know what these means???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am adding a proper answer in order to be clearly visible:

Workers are unix processes that will run the various celery tasks. As you can see in the documentation, the CELERYD_USER and CELERYD_GROUP determine the name of user and group these workers will be run in your Unix environment.

So, what happened initially in your case is that celery tried to start the worker with a user named "celery" which did not exist in your system. When you commented out these two options, then celery started the workers with the user that issued the command `sudo /etc/init.d/celeryd start` which in this case is the root (administrator) user (default is the current user).

However, it is recommended to run the workers as unpriviledged users and not as root for obvious reasons. So I recommend to actually add the celery user and group using the small tutorial found here http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-create-user-account/ and uncomment again the

```
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"
```

options.